# How do I integrate PRAW cleanly into my new Reddit Bot?

Tags: python-3.x, bots, reddit, praw

What am I doing wrong here?

I am following this guide: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html

I am VERY NEW to Reddit bots, so be gentle on me! I'm am also a Python 2 developer of 15 years thanks to the Ren'Py and Lemmasoft Forums community at renai.us. So this is what my bot looks like:

[image: screenshot of GANdroid God bot]

I am also following this guide to make it: https://hackernoon.com/build-a-serverless-reddit-bot-in-3-steps-with-node-js-and-stdlib-sourcecode-e5296b78fc64

I am stuck on Step 2, leading to this broken page: https://stdlib.com/@steve/src/reddit-bot/

I also kind of got stuck on PRAW as well, the Python Wrapper Reddit API. Please, any help is **greatly** appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows you trying to type Python code (`import praw`) into PowerShell. I don't know how to launch Python on PowerShell (though odds are good the command is `python3`), but you should actually launch python and then try the import again.

Comment: Also, your stdlib.com link has a 404 page not found error. I'm not sure what was supposed to be there but I can't see it.